# Bitbucket Rest API for getting Repo names under a Project

Tags: bitbucket-api

I'm trying to get the repo names under a Project using the Bitbucket API. The current link on the documentation says to use

```
curl -u username:pwd http://${bitbucket-url}/rest/api/1.0/projects/${projectkey}/repos
```

Response:

```
{
    "size": 1,
    "limit": 25,
    "isLastPage": true,
    "values": [
        {
            ***"slug": "my-repo",***
            "id": 1,
            "name": "My repo",
            "scmId": "git",
            "state": "AVAILABLE",
            "statusMessage": "Available",
            "forkable": true,
            "project": {
                "key": "PRJ",
                "id": 1,
                "name": "My Cool Project",
                "description": "The description for my cool project.",
                "public": true,
                "type": "NORMAL",
                "links": {
                    "self": [
                        {
                            "href": "http://link/to/project"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "public": true,
            "links": {
                "clone": [
                    {
                        "href": "ssh://git@<baseURL>/PRJ/my-repo.git",
                        "name": "ssh"
                    },
                    {
                        "href": "https://<baseURL>/scm/PRJ/my-repo.git",
                        "name": "http"
                    }
                ],
                "self": [
                    {
                        "href": "http://link/to/repository"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "start": 0
}
```

**But I only need the repo name from the response**

Comment: You can't directly get the repository name alone in a JSON response. There shall be other meta-data also available in it. You can handle it via a python script where you can pick-up the required info from the response. I shall post a script in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
from subprocess import call
import configparser
import subprocess
import json
import os

base_dir = os.getcwd()
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008

cmd = 'curl --url "' + bb_url + '?pagelen=100&page=' + str(page) + '" --user ' + bb_user + ':' + bb_pwd + ' --request GET --header "Accept: application/json"'
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS).communicate()
datastore = json.loads(output[0].decode("utf-8"))
size = datastore.get("size")
values = datastore.get("values")
if(len(values)) == 0:
    break
for repos in range(size):
    repo_name = values[repos]["values"]["slug"]
    f_initial = open (base_dir+"\\repositoryList.txt", "a+")
    f_initial.write(repo_name)
    f_initial.write("\n")
    f_initial.close()
page = page + 1
```

This script will help you get the list of all the repositories in your project and write it under the file repositoryList.txt

Answer (score 0):

With bash command

```
repoNamesJson=$(curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic <encoded user pasword here>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://yourstash/rest/api/1.0/projects/ad/repos?limit=100000)
repoNames=$(echo $repoNamesJson | awk -v RS=',' '/{"slug":/ {print}' | sed -e 's/{"slug":/''/g' | sed -e 's/"/''/g')
echo $repoNames
```

With python-stash library

```
import stashy

bitbucket = stashy.connect("host", "username", "password")
projects = bitbucket.projects.list()
repos = bitbucket.repos.list()

for project in projects:
    for repo in bitbucket.projects["%s" % (project["key"])].repos.list():
        print(repo["name"])
        print(repo["project"]['key'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BitBucket API [partial responses](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/partial-response) in order to limit the fields returned by the API.

Taking excerpts from the doc page:

> [...] use the `fields` query parameter.
> The fields parameter supports 3 modes of operation:
>
> - Removal of select fields (e.g. `-links`)
> - Pulling in additional fields not normally returned by an endpoint, while still getting all the default fields (e.g. `+reviewers`)
> - Omitting all fields, except those specified (e.g. `owner.display_name`)
>
> The fields parameter can contain a list of multiple comma-separated field names (e.g. `fields=owner.display_name,uuid,links.self.href`). The parameter itself is not repeated.

So in your case would be something like:

```sh
curl -u username:pwd 
  http://${bitbucket-url}/rest/api/1.0/projects/${projectkey}/repos?fields=values.slug
```

Though I must say that the JSON output is not flat, it will still retain its original structure:

```json
{
  "values": [
    {
      "slug": "your repo slug #1"
    },
    ...
```

So, if you actually want only a list with each repo slug on its own line, there's still some leg work to do.